# How to use joins in MySQL in this case

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have an employee table and a department table. How to can I use join to get the required below result. `manager_id` in the employee table is nothing but the employee id. Please help me to find out the answer

```
    Employee Table        

    id  | name  |   manager_id | department_id            
    ----------------------------------------              
    1   |  A    |   NULL       | 1                          
    2   |  B    |   1          | 2                        
    3   |  C    |   NULL       | 3                         
    4   |  D    |   3          | 2

     Department Table

     id    |   department_name
     -------------------------
     1    | Admin
     2    | HR
     3    | Finance 


    Required OutPut

    id  | name  |  manager_name   | department_name
    -----------------------------------------------
    1   |  A    |   NULL          | Admin                
    2   |  B    |   A             | HR                
    3   |  C    |   NULL          | Finance                
    4   |  D    |   C             | HR
```

Comment: Something like `select e.*, d.department_name from Employee as e join Department as d on e.department_id  = d.id` Join the `manager` table as well... or is the manager in the `employee` table?

Comment: This is good article to start with [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: Yes manager_id is same as employee id. There is no manager table. Thank you for replying

Comment: Sorry its a typo. There is no manager table

Comment: Add a left join with the employee table and the previous query should work.

Comment: Thanks . It's working fine now

Comment: @PritiranjanMishra You should accept one of the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use both Inner join and outer join

```
select E1.ID, E1.Name, E2.Name, D.department_name
FROM Employee E1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Employee E2 ON E2.ID = E1.manager_id
INNER JOIN Department D ON D.id = E1.department_id
```

Comment: You mean 'JOIN Employee E2'

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT E1.id, E1.name, E2.name as manager_name, D1.department_name
FROM Employee E1
LEFT JOIN Employee E2 ON (E1.id = E2.manager_id)
JOIN Department D2 ON (E1.department_id = D1.id)
```

You need first do the self join to find the manager name and after that nee to join with the Department  to find the appropriate Department name.

Comment: It will need to be a left join because some managers dont exist.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```
SELECT e.id as id, e.name as name e.manager_id as manager_id, 
d.department_name as department_name
FROM Employee as e 
JOIN Department as d 
ON e.department_id = d.id
```